# Receiving income as W-2 employee vs. 1099 contractor

Tags: united-states, taxes

My wife and I (both in the United States) file taxes jointly and make about $110,000 annually from our W-2 jobs.

I was offered a side gig that would pay an additional $48,000 per year. The company is letting me decide whether to work as a part-time W-2 employee for that gig, or an independent contractor who receives 1099 box 7 income.

By my calculations, receiving the income on a W-2 would be slightly better from a tax perspective, because we'd be taxed at 22% for the additional income, whereas with 1099 income we'd pay 21% (the business tax rate) plus self-employment payroll taxes of ~7.5 percent.

Is this analysis correct?  I am still wrapping my head around the recent tax law changes, and may be missing something.

(The side gig would not offer any benefits regardless of how I take the income, so my only real question to weigh is what is better from a tax perspective.)

Comment: #1 "*because we'd be taxed at 22% for the additional income*"  Are you taking the SS/Medicare tax that you also pay in a W-2 job?  #2 Do you want the extra hassle of having to pay quarterly taxes?

Comment: @RonJohn no, I had not thought about payroll taxes. Good point. I also realized I can put ~19% of the 1099 income into a SEP IRA, which provides other tax benefits. I wouldn't have that option with W-2 income through this job.

Answer (score 4):

For many years W-2 was preferred to 1099 because self-employment tax is 2x what you'd have withheld for social security and medicare if you were an employee getting a W-2. However as of 2018 there is a 20% pass-through income deduction that makes 1099 more attractive in most situations. Yes you'll pay self-employment tax instead of the employer paying half of payroll tax, but 20% of your business income won't be subject to income tax.

You don't have to set up an LLC or anything fancy, as a sole-proprietor your 1099 income will be reported on Schedule C (Profit or Loss from Business). If you incur any valid business expenses you will also be able to deduct those from your business revenue.

Here's an IRS FAQ on the [Qualified Business Income Deduction](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/tax-cuts-and-jobs-act-provision-11011-section-199a-qualified-business-income-deduction-faqs)

Comment: Great answer, but would add the question:  what is your goal?  If you are looking to turn this into a sustainable business, the go 1099.  If you are just looking to add some cash to your budget for a short term then you are probably better off with a W-2.